# Series approximation to integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, approximation

I would like to approximate the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty dy\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2y\sigma^2}\right)f(y),
$$
as a series expansion in the limit $\sigma\rightarrow 0$, where $f(y)$ is an arbitrary function. I can make a change of variables
$$
z=\frac{x-y}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}
$$
and then expand the integrand as a power series in $\sigma$ but that is a lot of manual manipulation (particularly because the change of variables is not injective).

Is there an easier way to approximate the integral in Mathematica?

## What I have so far

Define the integrand substitution rule

```
ruleZ=z -> (x - y)/(Sqrt[y] σ);
```

Obtain expressions for y in terms of z

```
slnY = Solve[z == (z /. ruleZ), y]
Out: {{y -> 1/2 (2 x + z^2 σ^2 - Sqrt[4 x z^2 σ^2 + z^4 σ^4])}, 
      {y -> 1/2 (2 x + z^2 σ^2 + Sqrt[4 x z^2 σ^2 + z^4 σ^4])}}
```

Define the integrand

```
ρ = σ Sqrt[y];
integrand = 1/Sqrt[2 Pi ρ^2] Exp[-(x - y)^2/(2 ρ^2)] f[y];
```

Change variables to $z$

```
integrandZ = FullSimplify[(integrand/Abs[D[z /. ruleZ, y]]) /. slnY];
Out: too nasty to reproduce
```

Expand the integrand as a series

```
approximateIntegrand=Series[integrandZ, {σ, 0, 2}];
Out: too nasty to reproduce
```

Integrate and obtain coefficients of $\sigma$

```
result = CoefficientList[Integrate[approximateIntegrand, {z, -∞, ∞}, σ]
Out: {{f[x], -(f[x]/(Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[x])) - Sqrt[2/π] Sqrt[x] Derivative[1][f][x], 
       Derivative[1][f][x] + 1/2 x (f^′′)[x]}, 
      {f[x], f[x]/(Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[x]) + Sqrt[2/π] Sqrt[x] Derivative[1][f][x], 
       Derivative[1][f][x] + 1/2 x (f^′′)[x]}}
```

In the limit $\sigma\rightarrow 0$ both solutions converge to $f(x)$ as expected. The first order terms are equal but opposite and the second order terms are equal.

## What is still causing me trouble

I would expect the first order term to vanish. The full solution should be a sum over all branches of the change of variables (cf. http://www.math.utah.edu/~levin/M5080/transforms.pdf page 3) but I obtain twice the result I expect in said case.

Comment: Why not evaluate the integral directly?

Comment: Because $f(y)$ is an arbitrary function.

Comment: (at) Julian: See my solution, which assumes that f[x] can be expanded into a power series.

Comment: Because you have replaced σ by ρ in the integrand, I think you should expand in ρ, not σ, which now is just a coefficient in the definition of z that has no connection to ρ.  More generally, it seems to me that you would do better to move this question to Mathematics.SE.  The issue is how to transform the integrand into a form that can be expanded in ρ, which is not a Mathematica.SE question.  Once that is solved, doing the expansion with Mathematica should be straightforward.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to define $\rho=\sigma\sqrt{y}$ which is now corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression in question is (we have replaced sigma by s)

```
g = Integrate[
  Exp[-(x - y)^2/(2 y s^2)] f[y] 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] y s^2], {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2 s^2 y}} f[y]}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{s^2 y}} \, dy$

First of all we notice that for `y>0`

```
"Limit[Exp[-(x - y)^2/(2 y s^2)] 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] y s^2], s -> 0] = 
 DiracDelta[x - y]"
```

Formally

```
Limit[Exp[-(x - y)^2/(2 y s^2)] 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] y s^2], 
 s -> 0, Assumptions -> {y > 0, x > 0, y != x}]

(*
Out[37]= 0
*)

In[39]:= Limit[Exp[-(x - y)^2/(2 y s^2)] 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] y s^2], 
 s -> 0, Assumptions -> {y > 0, x > 0, y == x}]

(*
Out[39]= \[Infinity]
*)
```

so that

```
Limit[g, s -> 0] = f[x]
```

Assuming now that `f[y]` can be expanded into a power series about `y = 0` and consider

```
g1 = Integrate[
  Exp[-(x - y)^2/(2 y s^2)] y^k/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] y s^2], {y, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> {s > 0, x^2 > 0}]

(*
Out[16]= (E^(x/s^2) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Abs[x]^(1/2 + k) BesselK[1/2 + k, Abs[x]/s^2])/s
*)
```

Now the series expansion about `s = 0` becomes

```
sg1 = Series[g1, {s, 0, 2}, Assumptions -> s > 0] // Normal

(*
Out[27]= E^(x/s^2 - Abs[x]/s^2) (1/2 k (1 + k) s^2 Abs[x]^(-1 + k) + Abs[x]^k)
*)
```

Let us distinguish the region `x<0` and `x>0`:

```
Simplify[sg1, x < 0]

(*
Out[28]= 1/2 E^((2 x)/s^2) (k (1 + k) s^2 - 2 x) (-x)^(-1 + k)
*)
```

Obviously, the exponential factor cannot be expanded about `s=0`.

```
Simplify[sg1, x > 0]

(*
Out[31]= 1/2 x^(-1 + k) (k s^2 + k^2 s^2 + 2 x)
*)
```

In the limit

```
Limit[%, s -> 0]

(*
Out[32]= x^k
*)
```

i.e. we rediscover the effect of the delta function.

Edit (Till Hoffmann): I thought I'd add to this answer to complete it.

Note that the expansion $\mathtt{sg1}=x^k + \sigma^2 \frac{k(1+k)}{2} x^{k-1}$ can be related to the Taylor expansion of 
$$
f(x) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \left(x f(x)\right),
$$
which is the desired series expansion in terms of the original function.

EDIT (Dr. Wolfgang Hintze, 28.02.15)

Let me add the general expansion in the form of Till Hoffmann, which I call s-expansion in the following

$$fs = \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{s^{2 j} }{j!2^{j}}\frac{\partial ^{2 j}\left(f(x) x^j\right)}{\partial x^{2 j}}$$

It is very interesting that this expression seems to hold not only for the powers of y considered up to now but for more general functions f(y).

In order to verify this hypothesis we shall study examples for other functions than simple powers of the s-expansion fs of our integral.

The s-expansion with a function f is given by

```
fs[x_, s_, f_, n_] := 
 Sum[s^(2 j) 1/(j! 2^j) D[x^(j) f, {x, 2 j}], {j, 0, n}]
```

Example 1: Simple pole on the negative real y-axis

The integral is numerically

```
gg1[x_, s_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[-(x - y)^2/(2 y s^2)] 1/(1 + y) 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] y s^2], {y,0, \[Infinity]}]
```

The first 3 terms of the s-expansion are

```
fs1[x_, s_] = Table[fs[x, s, 1/(1 + x), k], {k, 0, 2}] // Simplify

(*
{1/(1 + x), (-s^2 + (1 + x)^2)/(1 + x)^3, (
     3 s^4 - s^2 (1 + x)^2 + (1 + x)^4)/(1 + x)^5} 
*)
```

Graphs up to order s^4 for two values of s are

```
With[{s = 1}, 
 Plot[{gg1[x, s], {1/(1 + x), (-s^2 + (1 + x)^2)/(1 + x)^3, (
    3 s^4 - s^2 (1 + x)^2 + (1 + x)^4)/(1 + x)^5}}, {x, -1, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["s-expansion of integral\nf(y) = 1/(1+y), s = " <> ToString[s] <> 
     "\n", 14], AxesLabel -> {"x", "gg1[x]"}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[
     Style["Legend of curves:\nblue = integral, numeric (gg1)\nred = f(x)\n\
brown = O(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(2\)]\))\ngreen = \
O(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(4\)]\))", Medium], {1, 1.2}]}]]
(* 150228_s-expansion_f1 _s1.jpg *)
```

[image]

```
With[{s = 0.3}, 
 Plot[{gg1[x, s], {1/(1 + x), (-s^2 + (1 + x)^2)/(1 + x)^3, (
    3 s^4 - s^2 (1 + x)^2 + (1 + x)^4)/(1 + x)^5}}, {x, -1, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["s-expansion of integral\nf(y) = 1/(1+y), s = " <> 
     ToString[s] <> "\n", 14], AxesLabel -> {"x", "gg1[x]"}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[
     Style["Legend of curves:\nblue = integral, numeric (gg1)\nred = \
f(x)\nbrown = O(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(2\)]\))\ngreen = O(\!\(\
\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(4\)]\))", Medium], {1, 1.2}]}]]
(* 150228_s-expansion_f1 _s0-3.jpg *)
```

[image]

Example 2: Simple conjugate poles on the imaginary y-axis

The integral is numerically

```
gg2[x_, s_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[-(x - y)^2/(2 y s^2)] 1/(1 + y^2) 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] y s^2], {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

The first 3 terms of the s-expansion are

fs2[x, s]

```
(*
{1/(1 + x^2), (s^2 x (-3 + x^2) + (1 + x^2)^2)/(1 + x^2)^3, (
 s^2 x (-3 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^2 + (1 + x^2)^4 - 
  3 s^4 (1 - 10 x^2 + 5 x^4))/(1 + x^2)^5} 
*)
```

Graphs up to order s^4 for two values of s are

```
With[{s = 1}, 
 Plot[{gg2[x, s], {1/(1 + x^2), (
    s^2 x (-3 + x^2) + (1 + x^2)^2)/(1 + x^2)^3, (
    s^2 x (-3 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^2 + (1 + x^2)^4 - 
     3 s^4 (1 - 10 x^2 + 5 x^4))/(1 + x^2)^5}}, {x, -1, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["s-expansion of integral\nf(y) = 1/(1+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \
\(2\)]\)), s = " <> ToString[s] <> "\n", 14], AxesLabel -> {"x", "gg2[x]"}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[
     Style["Legend of curves:\nblue = integral, numeric (gg1)\nred = f(x)\n\
brown = O(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(2\)]\))\ngreen = \
O(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(4\)]\))", Medium], {1, 1.2}]}]]
(* 150228_s-expansion_f2 _s0-9.jpg *)
```

[image]

```
With[{s = 0.4}, 
 Plot[{gg2[x, s], {1/(1 + x^2), (
    s^2 x (-3 + x^2) + (1 + x^2)^2)/(1 + x^2)^3, (
    s^2 x (-3 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^2 + (1 + x^2)^4 - 
     3 s^4 (1 - 10 x^2 + 5 x^4))/(1 + x^2)^5}}, {x, -1, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["s-expansion of integral\nf(y) = \
1/(1+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)), s = " <> ToString[s] <> 
     "\n", 14], AxesLabel -> {"x", "gg2[x]"}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[
     Style["Legend of curves:\nblue = integral, numeric (gg1)\nred = \
f(x)\nbrown = O(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(2\)]\))\ngreen = O(\!\(\
\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(4\)]\))", Medium], {1, 1.2}]}]]
(* 150228_s-expansion_f2 _s0-4.jpg *)
```

[image]

We see that the agreement is what is to expected in the sense of an asymptotic expansion.

Conclusion: the formula for $fs$ seems to be valid for a broader class of function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Using the expansion $\mathtt{sg1}=x^k + \sigma^2 \frac{k(1+k)}{2} x^{k-1}$, the first term reproduces the desired function $f(x)$ in a Taylor expansion. How can I express the second term in terms of the original function and its derivatives? It almost looks like a second derivative. I'll have a play with it.

Comment: Dr. Wolfgang Hintze, thank you very much for your help. I would like to mention you in the acknowledgements of the paper for which I required the above series expansion. Please drop me a line at t.hoffmann13(AT)imperial(DOT)ac(DOT)uk and I will send you a draft before publication.

Comment: Although this is an elegant solution, it may be valid only if `f` is an [entire function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function), so that its series converges throughout the range of integration.  If not, then some additional terms associated with the poles of `f` in the complex plane may arise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I agree completely. I tried e.g. two poles f[y] = 1/(1+y^2), without success. The y-integral must be split into one over (0..1) and the other over (1,oo). But the resulting integrals had no closed expressions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for the hint which led me to consider other functions than powers successfully. See my edit of today.